# Calculate a weekly streak in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table storing the dates of people entering their weight into our app, and I need to figure out how (or whether) I can write a query to determine how many consecutive weeks they've weighed in.

There are many resources that give examples of how to calculate streaks in general, but the weekly part has me pretty flummoxed. Honestly I'm not even really sure where to start. My pseudocode looks something like: "Count the number of consecutive weeks with at least 1 weighin", but the consecutive weeks part is tricky.

Has anyone ever implemented something like this?

PostgreSQL 9.3 is what I'm using. The dates of the weighins are of `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` type.

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089746/calculating-the-longest-binge-viewing-streak-using-sql?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Actually you asked for a cube and sql-query it is not great idea but

```
select log_id, 
    sum(
    case when "dt" between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-01'+interval'1 month' and "dr">=user.registration_date::date and exists(select 1 from user.activity ph where ph.user_id = log_id and ph.dt::date  between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-01'+interval'1 month' ) then 1 
    when "dt" between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-01'+interval'1 month'  and "dt">=user.registration_date::date and not exists(select 1 from user.activity ph where ph.user_id = log_id and ph.dt::date between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-01'+interval'1 month' ) then 0
    when "dt" between '2012-01-01' and '2012-01-01'+interval'1 month' and "dt"< user.registration_date::date then -1 else null end) as "2012-01",
    sum(case when "dt" between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-01'+interval'1 month' and "dt">=user.registration_date::date and exists(select 1 from user.activity ph where ph.user_id = log_id and ph.dt::date between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-01'+interval'1 month' ) then 1
    when "dt" between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-01'+interval'1 month'  and "dt">=user.registration_date::date and 
                     not exists(select 1 from user.activity ph where ph.user_id = log_id and ph.dt::date between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-01'+interval'1 month' ) then 0
    when "dt" between '2012-02-01' and '2012-02-01'+interval'1 month'  and "dt"<user.registration_date::date then -1 else null end) as "2012-02"
            from user.activity where dt between '2012-01-01' and '2012-03-01'  group by log_id
```

Example of user activity by month
Matrix
`Value >0` - user already registered and have activity in selected month
`Value =0`  user already registered but have no activity in selected month
`Value < 0` user have not registered in selected month

Comment: The question is in terms of weekly streak rather than monthly.  The SQL is daunting, not least because the lines are unreadably long.  It also looks like you've hard-coded the dates into the query; how would you generalize it to handle any range of dates?

Comment: It's better to avoid sql and use generator cubes - he asks for a cube. But there is  one way in sql. Also you can create query string in function and then execute it to avoid hard-code for dates range. But btter use cube generators